# VueJS invert value in v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, boolean, v-model

Here my code :

```
<input
   v-model="comb.inactive"
   type="checkbox"
   @click="setInactive(comb.id_base_product_combination)"
>
```

I need to apply the invert of the comb.inactive on the v-model.

Here what i tried :

```
<input
    v-model="comb.inactive == 1 ? 0 : 1"
    type="checkbox"
    @click="setInactive(comb.id_base_product_combination)"
>



<input
    v-model="comb.inactive == 1 ? false : true"
    type="checkbox"
    @click="setInactive(comb.id_base_product_combination)"
>
```

Do you have others ideas ?

Comment: "Do you have others ideas?"  Yes, use a Vue computed.  Which does not warrant an answer, but rather, a deeper understanding of Vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
<input
   v-model="comb.inactive"
   type="checkbox"
   @click="setInactive(comb.id_base_product_combination)"
>
```

```
mounted(){
      this.comb['inactive'] = !(this.comb['inactive']);
}
```

For better practice, you can use `computed`:

```
<input
   v-model="checkedItem"
   type="checkbox"
   @click="setInactive(comb.id_base_product_combination)"
>
```

```
computed: {
      checkedItem: {
        get: function () {
          return !this.comb['inactive'];
        },
        set: function (newVal) {
          console.log("set as you want")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider using `true-value` and `false-value` as shortcuts:

```
<input
    v-model="comb.inactive"
    type="checkbox"
    :true-value="false"
    :false-value="true"
>
```

Or in this case, where you may be looking for alternating integers, you can just set them directly.

```
<input
    v-model="comb.inactive"
    type="checkbox"
    :true-value="1"
    :false-value="0"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *invert* the v-model, then just make a custom input component!

#### `checkbox-inverted`

```
Vue.component('reverse-checkbox', {
  props: ['value', 'label'],
  template: `
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        :checked="valueInverse"
        @input="onInputChanged"
      />
      <span>{{label}}</span>
    </label>
  `,
  computed: {
    valueInverse() {
      return !this.value;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInputChanged(e) {
      this.$emit('input', this.valueInverse);
    },
  },
});
```

#### Usage

Then you can use it with `v-model` like any other input component. [more information about custom inputs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

```html
<reverse-checkbox
  v-model="invertedModel"
  label="This checkbox will show the inverted value"
></reverse-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the event and property of checkbox instead of using v-model.

```
<input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox"
    :id="day.label"
    :checked="!day.is_closed" 
    @change="($event) => day.is_closed = !day.is_closed"
/>
```

For example in my case, I have a checkbox HTML element.
so I set `checked` and `change` property.

- `<input>` with text types and `<textarea>` elements use `value` property and `input` event;
- `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="radio">` use `checked` property and `change` event;
- `<select>` use `value` as a prop and `change` as an event.